# Codigo Python y Pandas resuelve mal un replace

Tags: python

Estoy intentando que un código de Python de Google Collab haga lo siguiente: Evalúe una columna la cual contiene keywords y es posible que estas keywords tengan un enlace asociado. Por otra parte, tengo la columna descripciones, la cual simplemente contiene descripciones de producto de un ecommerce:

```py
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

df_keywords = pd.read_excel("NegritasyEnlaces.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

df_descripciones = pd.read_excel("Descripciones.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

def resaltar_keywords(row):
    descripcion = row['Descripciones']
    keywords = df_keywords['Keywords'].tolist()

    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in descripcion:
            enlace = df_keywords.loc[df_keywords['Keywords'] == keyword, 'Enlace'].iloc[0]
            if pd.notna(enlace):
                descripcion = descripcion.replace(keyword, f'<a href="{enlace}"><strong>{keyword}</strong></a>', 1)
            else:
                descripcion = descripcion.replace(keyword, f'<strong>{keyword}</strong>', 1)

    return descripcion
print(df_keywords)

df_descripciones['Descripcion_Formateada'] = df_descripciones.apply(resaltar_keywords, axis=1)


df_descripciones.to_excel("Descripciones_Formateadas.xlsx", index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

El problema es que estoy intentando que solo coloque un enlace por cada keyword. Es posible que haya keywords contenidas en otras. Por ejemplo, es posible que exista la keyword "HP 12" y "HP 121A". en este caso, quiero que escoja la keywords más larga y SOLO la más larga.